# When not use local.xml for theme development in magento

Tags: magento

I have heard a lot of people in the Magento community mention the benefits of using a `local.xml` for Magento theme development

I can understand the benefits and I actually can't think of any cases where its use could be detrimental.

Are there specific situations where `local.xml` is a bad choice?  If there are, then what would those be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MagePsycho's points are all correct, so I'll offer the following adding onto them.

`local.xml` layout file is only appropriate for the end-implementer, of course - makers of distributed modules should ensure that their modules configure & use a new layout update file. This may or may not be assumed in the original question, but it bears mentioning.

Also, in the case of a multisite installation, if several site themes share a common set of layout updates, but one or more site requires further updates, then it is ideal to create a custom module which configures a layout file to collect the common local layout changes. This allows for theme-specific `local.xml` files which do not contain duplicated layout updates.

Comment: This is a better answer than MagePsycho's as it provides 2 examples of when *not* to use the local.xml (which is the Op's question).

Answer (score 2):

The `local.xml` file of your theme's layout is always loaded last. Therefore, you can override the existing layout node and customize your layout according to your project's requirements.

Also, using `local.xml` is upgrade-proof in the sense that a single layout xml contains only necessary xml layout updates.

It may take you some time to adjust the design via `local.xml` because you can't comment an unnecessary block's nodes; you must remove the block via xml remove nodes. Also, you have to take care while sorting the block positions.

However, once you are done with one theme using `local.xml` then you can easily reuse the same concept (with some modification) for other themes.

Overall, using local.xml:

- Makes your system more upgrade-proof
- Saves time for future projects
- Fewer number of files = less overhead :)

Hope this makes some sense :)

Cheers!

Comment: Wasn't the question: When **not** to use local.xml ??

Comment: Yeah Drew, seems to have eye slip ;)